# Center a th regardless of the size of the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working on a page that has existing css. I want to add using an existing css colour and shade that is defined for a `th`.
Now this `th` is added as the **last** row on the table.
What I want is to have any text that appears in this `th` to be centralised in relation to the enclosing `tr`.
What I did so far and somewhat works is to use `colspan=7` and the content of the `th` appears somewhat in the center of the row and the table. (There are 14 columns).
How can I do it without hardcoding numbers in a more generic fashion? I.e. some how center it regardless of the number of columns of the table.

Comment: Can you show your HTML + CSS?

Comment: I think you might have to consider a separate solution from using a table

Answer (score 2):

Use a table's built in `<caption>` element, and then position it at the bottom using `caption-side:bottom`. Should allow for some sort of centered text no matter how many columns you have. Support for `caption-side` seems to go back to IE8, according to http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/caption-side.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/designingsean/K9Fcw/

HTML:

```
<table class="caption-bottom">
  <caption>Table Caption</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>lksjf</td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.caption-bottom {
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

Comment: `seems to go back to IE8` How back is that?

Comment: Far enough in my mind. If you are having to support IE7, then this issue is probably the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the problem as you're missing some code, but wouldn't this simple table be enough (I hope I constructed you as you think it should be):
http://plnkr.co/edit/TxGQZX0NPoLZsR77kQ70?p=preview

```
<table style="border:1px solid">
  <tr>
    <td>My td 1 Content and all</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>My td 2 Content and all</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>My heading 1</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This way my th is centralised.